# Simulate long press of KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK

Tags: android, key, usb, headset

I am trying to programmatically control incoming call (Accept and reject) Target Android 6.0 and above in my companion app.

### Working method but deprecated

telecomManager.acceptCall() and telecomManager.endCall()
This method is working fine till Android 10 and also in virtual Android 11 but in developers site it says it is deprecated.

```
This method was deprecated in API level 29.
Companion apps for wearable devices should use the InCallService API instead.
```

### Partially working method

By simulation headset press button key event found that the call can be controlled. The following is my implementation

```
void sendHeadsetHookLollipop() {
    MediaSessionManager mediaSessionManager =  (MediaSessionManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE);

 

    try {
        List<MediaController> mediaControllerList = mediaSessionManager.getActiveSessions 
                     (new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiverService.class));

 

        for (MediaController m : mediaControllerList) {
             if ("com.android.server.telecom".equals(m.getPackageName())) {
                 m.dispatchMediaButtonEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
                 log.info("HEADSETHOOK sent to telecom server");
                 break;
             }
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        log.error("Permission error. Access to notification not granted to the app.");      
    }  
}
```

in the above piece of code, I am able to answer the ringing call. To reject, I need to simulate a long press of the same KeyEvent.

### 1.How to achieve long press of a keyEvent?

### 2. Is there any other non deprecated implementation method for the above need?

### 3.In the telecomManager class, they have suggested to implement InCallService . How to implement InCallService without making my app default app?

Comment: This is behavior Google doesn't want apps to be able to do.  Every so often people find a way to do it, and every time they do Google removes it in the next release.  You're not supposed to be able to end a call unless you're the registered dialer app.  You won't find a way to do it that works across all versions, and for most versions you won't find any way at all.

Comment: Thank you @Gabe sechan . just curious to know, how the companion apps(Galaxy wearable, Mi fit etc.) are working?

Comment: System apps have higher levels of permissions they can use.  You can use them as well if your device is rooted and you know how to make your app a system app (it required putting the apk in the right directory via command line and rebooting the phone), but it won't work for an app you intend to put on the play store.

Comment: But Companion apps are not system apps, How it is achieved there?

Comment: Anybody have any other solutions for this? I been got stuck in this.

Comment: Hi @mani, do you have a solution for this? Basically I have the same question. How to use InCallService without replacing default dialer?

Comment: Some information could be found in the Javadoc here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/764a90c200b232fbfcd7a5b3f56c82fea5baf21e/telecomm/java/android/telecom/InCallService.java and here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#CALL_COMPANION_APP

Comment: Hmm, finally I think the InCallService Api for Companion apps is a trap.

Comment: @Christopher looks like , well I still didn't get the solution for this.